# .gitignore revert a rule in nested subfolders

Tags: git, gitignore, subdirectory

### Problem

I have a folder structure like:

```
.gitignore
notebooks/
notebooks/nb1.ipynb
notebooks/nb1_outputs.something
notebooks/folderA/
notebooks/folderA/nb2.ipynb
notebooks/folderA/nb2_outputs.someothers
notebooks/folderA/folderAA/nb3.ipynb
notebooks/folderA/folderAA/nb3_outputs.someothers
...
```

I want to ignore all stuff in the `notebooks/` folder except `*.ipynb` files.

### What I have tried

I wrote in the `.gitignore` like this:

```
/notebooks/*
!**.ipynb
```

but this did not work for `nb2.ipynb`, probably because it is in a subfolder which has been ignored by `/notebooks/*`.

Though I can write manually:

```
/notebooks/*.*
!/notebooks/*.ipynb
/notebooks/*/*.*
!/notebooks/*/*.ipynb
/notebooks/*/*/*.*
!/notebooks/*/*/*.ipynb
```

Is there a way to do this more easily?

### Supplementary info

```
(base) ➜  git-test git:(master) ✗ cat .gitignore
notebooks/**
!notebooks/**.ipynb
(base) ➜  git-test git:(master) ✗ tree          
.
└── notebooks
    ├── folderA
    │   ├── nb2.ipynb
    │   └── nb2.out
    ├── nb1.ipynb
    └── nb1.out

2 directories, 4 files
(base) ➜  git-test git:(master) ✗ git status    
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
(base) ➜  git-test git:(master) ✗ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just figured this out. Just write:

```
# ignore all files in subfolders
/notebooks/**/*.*
# revert for notebooks
!/notebooks/**/*.ipynb
```

This works for me, though it is still prone to files without extensions.

Alternatively, a more general solution from @torek:

```
# add this to the end of .gitignore:
!*/
```

This disables the directory optimization, because `!*/` inverts the ignoring of any directory or subdirectory.

Comment: For reverting, it would need a *preceding* exclamation mark (`!`)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Thanks, my mistake in writing this answer. Edited now.

Comment: Note that you can also use a brute-force rule to completely disable the directory optimizations that `.gitignore` normally enables. Just add `!*/` to the end of your `.gitignore`: now Git must look inside every subdirectory, no matter how deeply nested or totally irrelevant it might be, just in case it might contain an un-ignored file.

Comment: @torek Perfect! Exactly what I want.